# Coverity installation and database setup (cov-install-gui)

Tags: coverity-prevent

I am new to using coverity and this might not be a very challenging question, but I would appreciate it greatly if someone could guide me through the process of setting up the .

I first ran the following command:

cov-configure --compiler /usr/bin/gcc --comptype gcc

This created a few files pertaining to the above command in my /config directory.

The real problem occurs when I run the cov-install-gui command to setup the defect manager and the database, I am not sure what to input for the --datadir option. When I passed in an empty directory (as a mere attempt), it complains saying that coverity_db does not exist within the empty directory.

Its not clear to me as to where I can find the coverity_db directory or how to install it? 
I feel like I am missing something from the cov-configure command, but I am not sure.

Also I am using, Linux CentOS 5.4 and Coverity prevent 4.5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old and no longer supported version of Coverity Prevent (4.5 or older) since you are referencing the Defect Manager.

Current version is 6.0 so you should not be using the version that you are.

The answer to your question is that data directory is any directory that will be used to write the results and GUI files, so you can just specify any file path that doesn't already exist  and it will create the directory and the files it needs in that directory.